# Using gdb to calculate return address

Tags: c

I'm currently doing a school project right now, and I'm lost on using gdb on ubuntu to find a buffer overflow vulnerability.

I've never used gdb before, but did a little bit of research on the internet and when I used the "disas main" command I was quite overwhelmed at what I was looking at.

I was wondering if someone can walk me through on how to debug this program or any other programs and show me how the return address is found.

I have this code here:

```
/* This program has a buffer overflow vulnerability. */
/* Our task is to exploit this vulnerability */
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int bof(char *str)
{
    char buffer[12];
    /* The following statement has a buffer overflow problem */
    strcpy(buffer, str);
    return 1;
}

    int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char str[512];
    FILE *badfile;
    badfile = fopen("badfile", "r");
    fread(str, sizeof(char), 5122, badfile);
    bof(str);
    printf("Returned Properly\n");
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Which function's return address are you looking for? Generally speaking, the gdb `bt` (or `backtrace`) command will give you the backtrace of all stack frames including return addresses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the debugger you can see the disassembled code, just put a break point to the `ret` operand of your function. When it stops, see the value of the `esp` register which points you to the stack address. Then explore the memory at this address and the first 4 (depending on your platform) bytes will give you the address which will be used to return to.